# Odd thread behaviors

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

The next code normally prints BA but sometimes it can print BBAA, BAAB, ... How is it possible to get two A or B with it?!  However this code never prints three A or B. Both functions (produce and consume) run a lot of threads. Many thanks in advance.

```
int permission;
void set_permission(int v) {
    permission = v;
    printf("%c", v + 'A');fflush(stdin);
}
void* produce(void*) {
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mr1);
        set_permission(1);
        while (permission == 1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mr1);
    }
}
void* consume(void*) {
    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mr2);
        while (permission == 0);
        set_permission(0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mr2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` causes udnefined behaviour; don't do it

Comment: I see 2 unrelated mutexes. Looks like you can remove your sync procedures and get the same result.

Comment: what are the references to two different mutexs about?  if the code is trying to  protect the variable `permission` then all the mutex references should be to the same mutex.  Suggest: `for( ;; ) { while( !permission );  pthread_mutex_lock( &mr1 ); set_permission( 1 );  pthread_mutex_unlock( &mr1 ); }`  the consumer thread would look VERY similar AND would use the same mutex

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, the purpose (although incorrectly implemented) is to avoid race conditions on the access of the variable: `permissions`.

Comment: Multiple threads running busy wait loops... this doesn't look good. Is permission atomic?

Comment: My code never prints three A or B. My question is how to explain two A or B in results? I don't ask to correct my code.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c", v + 'A');fflush(stdin);`  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) suggest using: `printf("%c", v + 'A');  fflush( stdout );`

Comment: How many 'A's or 'B's are printed is strictly a random detail.  The actual problem is the code is wrong.

Comment: Normally the answer to such questions is "your code has undefined behaviour so absolutely anything could happen". The real questiin is what causes UB and how to fix it.

Comment: The permission global may not be coherent w.r.t. other threads, depending on CPU coherency and/or compiler optimization.  The hot while loops are not helping as well.  Also, as printf() buffers to stdout, the fflush(stdin) probably doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your threads are not synchronized, as they are not using the same mutex.

The other thread can by chance only mange to set `permission` to 1 or 0, but not manage to produce output yet. In which case it appears as if the first thread ran two full rounds.

The write by the corresponding thread can also get entirely *lost*, when the memory content is synchronized between cores and both threads wrote. The mutex also prevents this from happening, because it establishes a strict memory access order, which, to put it simple, guarantees that everything which has happened under the protection of one mutex is fully visible to the next user of the same mutex.

Printing the same character 3 or more times would be very unlikely, as there is at most one write happening in between, so at most one lost write, or one out of order output. That's not guaranteed though.

If you are working on a system with no implicit memory synchronisation at all, your code could also just straight out deadlock, as the writes done under one mutex never propagate to the users of the other one. ( Doesn't actually happen because there is still some synchronisation introduced by the IO operations. )

Comment: I placed printf before the assignment and this eliminated all double characters! Thanks a million!

Comment: @vollitwr As long as you are not using the same mutex, this still only eliminated the out-of-order output. Your code is still vulnerable to lost writes, unless `permission` is either an [atomic](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or you are using the same mutex. That error is much harder to provoke, but it can still happen.